# How to get the selected label from a html <select>?

Tags: javascript, html

HTML Javascript question

to get the selected value of a input-select I can use

```
<select id="gender" name="gender" class="style12">
    <option selected="selected">ALL</option>
    <option>Male Only</option>
    <option>Female Only</option>
</select>

document.getElementById('gender').value
```

is there any easy way for me to get the selected label (i.e. ALL / Male Only / Female Only) with javascript?

Thanks a lot for reading.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
var el = document.getElementById('gender');
var text = el.options[el.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 17):

suggested jQuery version:

```
jQuery("#gender").find("option[value='" + jQuery("#gender").val() + "']").text()
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
var label = document.getElementById('gender')[document.getElementById('gender').selectedIndex].innerHTML;
```

Comment: whats the difference between your answer and accepted answer :p

Answer (score 0):

A more modern way of doing it is:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('gender').selectedOptions[0].textContent)
```

```html
<select id="gender" name="gender">
    <option>ALL</option>
    <option selected>Male Only</option>
    <option>Female Only</option>
</select>
```