# Javascript load html

Tags: javascript, include

I just got a problem, i have a select tag with some different options.

Now I want to check which of these options is selected by the user.

Then i want to load a new html file into this site (depends on which options the user has checked) width javascript, how do i do that ?

Here is the select menu

```
<select>
   <option>option1</option>
   <option>option2</option>
   <option>option3</option>
   <option>option4</option>
   <option>option5</option>
   <option>option6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Did you make an attempt yourself?

Comment: So you want to redirect a user to a new page based on their selection?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903741/how-to-get-the-selected-label-from-a-html-select and make try yourself

Comment: You may want to add `value` attribute to your `option` elements. This value should contain a string keeping a path to another page. Also `select` needs an `id` attribute. Then you can read the value of `select`: `document.getElementById('select_id').value` gives you the value of the selected option. You can use this value when setting `location.href`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the html code:

```
<select onchange="changeIt();" id="formula">
        <option>option1</option>
        <option>option2</option>
        <option>option3</option>
        <option>option4</option>
        <option>option5</option>
        <option>option6</option>

    </select>
```

Then following javascript code will load new local html pages:

```
function changeIt()
{
    var fName = document.getElementById("formula");
    var fText = fName.options[fName.selectedIndex].text;
    if(fText=="option1")
    {
        window.location.href = "abc.html";
    }
    else if(fText == "option2")
    {
        window.location.href = "xyz.html";      
    }
}
```

Both abc.html and xyz.html are local html files.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery is so simple to add this code

```
  $(function(){
    var includes = $('[data-include]');
    jQuery.each(includes, function(){
      var file = 'views/' + $(this).data('include') + '.html';
      $(this).load(file);
    });
  });
</script>

Use jquery
```