# How to get the selected labels from a html <select>?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I can get ONE label from the selected items in the list, but I can select multiple items but I don't know how to get the labels from all selected items.

This question is based upon: [How to get the selected label from a html <select>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903741/how-to-get-the-selected-label-from-a-html-select)

Comment: What do you mean by "the labels"?

Comment: My <select> has a few items which are shown as labels in the aformentioned <select>. That's what I mean by labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the NodeList that is `referenceToTheSelect.options` (using a `for` loop). Test the `selected` property of each element in it. If `selected` is true, do whatever you like with the label / value.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery, it work like this,

```
 $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
       console.log( $( this ).val() ); // for the text
 });
```