# How do I find a dropdown value from a dropdown label

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a dropdown as

```
 <select name="Countries" id="Countries">
  <option value="USA">United States of America</option>
  <option value="AUS">Australia</option>
 </select>
```

Suppose on load of a page I get a sample text as "Australia" then I want to get its respective value as "AUS"

I want to get dropdown value from its label.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Please elaborate. What label are you talking about?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the selected label from a html <select>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903741/how-to-get-the-selected-label-from-a-html-select)

Comment: @TheProvost I mean the inner html of the selected value.I want to get its respective text.

Comment: does @cport1 answer satisfy your problem?

Comment: Your title is *"How do I find a dropdown label from a dropdown value"* and finally you're asking  - *"I want to get dropdown value from its label."* Your question is not clear

Answer (score 1):

Would be something like this:

```
var e = document.getElementById("Countries");
var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: Thanks @cport1 your answer helped me partially.I just changed var e.options[e.selectedIndex].value to  e.options[e.selectedIndex].innerHTML and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who helped me here.
Below is the solution to get label from the selected value of a droddown.

```
var e = document.getElementById("Countries");
var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
```

Comment: You can also do e.options[e.selectedIndex].text

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/mm18qrwd/1/

I think you don't have index of selected element,
hence,

```
var value = "";
Array.prototype.slice.
call(document.
     getElementById("Countries").
     options).
forEach(function(option){
    if(option.text == "Australia") {
        value = option.getAttribute("value")
    }
})
alert(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using JQuery, this code `$('#Countries').val()` will return what you want.