# Display Map value in a div tag while onchange event

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, jsp

in my JSP I'm having a drop down to list all available departments, when client is selecting a department, by AJAX I'm bringing list of all employees in the next drop down.

For AJAX purpose I'm using a `HahMap<Integer, String>` and my response file is

```
<%@ page contentType="text/xml;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-tld/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-tld/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<response>
     <logic:iterate id="map" name="optionMap">
         <option>
            <optionvalue><bean:write name="map" property="key"/></optionvalue>
            <optionlabel><bean:write name="map" property="value"/></optionlabel>
         </option>
    </logic:iterate>
</response>
```

My Employee drop down code is

```
<html:select property="employeeId" styleId="employeeId" styleClass="combo" onchange="displayEmployeeName(this.value)">
    <html:option value=""><bean:message key="knowledgepro.admin.select"/></html:option>
    <logic:notEmpty name="hlAdmissionForm" property="employees">
        <html:optionsCollection property="employees" label="value" value="key"/>
    </logic:notEmpty>
</html:select>
```

So you can see that value of drop down is the id (key of the HashMap) of that Employee and label is his/her name(value of HashMap).

Up to this everything is working fine, but now the requirement is to display the selected Employee name in the next table cell `<td>`.

You can see in the code for Employee drop down I'm calling a JS function which is

```
function displayEmployeeName(employeeName) {
    document.getElementById("studentName").innerHTML = employeeName;
}
```

But because I'm passing `this.value` at the onchange event of Employee drop down instead of Employee name Employee id is displayed. So can anybody tell me how to get the value of `HashMap` at the onchange event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this.value` to get the employeeId, and then ask for the name using your employee HashMap in your function

```
function displayEmployeeName(empId) {
    document.getElementById("studentName").innerHTML = myMap[empId];
}
```

If you don't have your map globally available, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/903748)

The reason this.value returns your id is because your map is "Integer,String", which means that value in the map is the employeeName, and the key is employeeId. However, in your select onChange-event you are reffering to the value in the select-element, which you assigned the id of the Employee.

Comment: Thank you **John** that link really helped.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed my JS function to this and I was able to get the answer.

```
function displayEmployeeName(empId) {
      jQuery("#employeeId").find("option[value='" + jQuery("#employeeId").val() + "']").text()
}
```

Thank you for your responses, I'm sorry that I described the question in the wrong way, this is what I should have asked.

[How to get the selected label from a html ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903741/how-to-get-the-selected-label-from-a-html-select)